# ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock - Change style of message box C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using asp.net web design. I'm using ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock to display a successful message and a error Message.This is validation for a Gridview. Can I change the style of this Message Box? I have this code below

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('At least on rating must be selected per question')", true);

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Results saved Successfully')", true);
```

thank you for the help

Comment: No, This is simple Alert message box provided by system, you may need JQuery Dialog box for this purpose.

Comment: Note that "alert" has a "blocking thread" effect, while other "custom  boxes" don't have this effect. (only as a side note)
Here is a sample of jAlert: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/

Comment: How do i call the jquery message on the server side?